# matlab url authentication for imread

Tags: matlab, authentication, ip-camera, urlread, imread

How can I use the IMREAD function with a URL that requires basic authentication in MATLAB 2014a? (not the old matlab).
It works well for matlab R2013a as described in this link
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100103-can-i-perform-basic-authentication-with-urlread-in-matlab
but the above method doesn't work for matlab R2014a because it has different coding in its function files.
help needed.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Read carefully. The instructions at the the link you gave are for pre-R2013a, which needs to be "hacked" to support this functionality. I have not tried it, but `urlread` in R2013a+ should support this directly – see the `'Authentication'` property.

Comment: but how to use it for imread?. as imread calls urlwrite function itself , how can i give username password arguements for imread?

Comment: BY using this function i can authenticate a url and copy its content , but how to do this for imread to get ipcamera images.                    url=urlread('http://192.168.0.1','Authentication','Basic','Username','admin','Password','admin');

Comment: if i do this , i get error :    img = imread('http://192.168.194.20/image/jpeg.cgi','Authentication','Basic','Username','admin','Password','admin');
Error using imread (line 330)
Can't read URL "http://192.168.194.20/image/jpeg.cgi".